# RStudio: set virtualenvs to specific path

Tags: r, rstudio, reticulate

So, I'll have a variaty of projects that need to source python scripts.

As I understand, reticulate pkg can help us work with virtualenvs inside RStudio.

virtualenv_list() will return the available names of the virutalenvs.

But since I already have a folder with all my virtual envs, I'd like to use it instead of the default folder:

from: https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/reference/virtualenv-tools.html

> Virtual environments are by default located at ~/.virtualenvs. You can
>   change this behavior by defining the WORKON_HOME environment variable.

**How do I define the WORK_HOME variable?**

Path to the folder, where I've different virtualenvs:

```
/home/gonzales/Escritorio/virtual_envs
```

Path to one of my virtualenvs:

```
/home/gonzales/Escritorio/virtual_envs/stickers-gallito-env/
```

I've found this code to find the RProfile to work on:

```
> candidates <- c( Sys.getenv("R_PROFILE"),
+                  file.path(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), "etc", "Rprofile.site"),
+                  Sys.getenv("R_PROFILE_USER"),
+                  file.path(getwd(), ".Rprofile") )
> 
> Filter(file.exists, candidates)
[1] "/usr/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site" "/home/gonzales/.Rprofile"
```

If I edit the  `Rprofile.R` with:

```
file.edit("/home/gonzales/.Rprofile")
```

And then save the changes:

```
WORKON_HOME = "/home/gonzales/Escritorio/virtual_envs/"
```

And then try:

```
library(reticulate)

virtualenv_list()
```

I'll get:

```
character(0)
```

*Why is it not working?*

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=es_PE.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=es_PE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=es_PE.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=es_PE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=es_PE.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=es_PE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=es_PE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.4 tools_3.4.4    yaml_2.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/730/how-do-i-set-environment-variables for different ways to set environment variables in ubuntu.

Add the following to /etc/environment: `WORKON_HOME="/home/gonzales/Escritorio/virtual_envs"` then log out and back in again.

Then running `virtualenv_list()` should list the virtual envs you have in that location.